# WebJars not accessible in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, webjars

I want to make a webpage based on Spring MVC, Semantic-UI framework and Gradle build tool. The problem is that, the JSP pages can't access the Semantic files while I trying to import them from WebJars. When I'm using import from cdnjs it working really nice.

Ok, my code below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.web)
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
}
```

index.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
      <!--
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='webjars/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.css'>
      <script src='webjars/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.js'></script> -->

      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.css'>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.js'></script>

    <title>Index Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <spring:message code="Index.WelcomeText"></spring:message>
  <div class="ui animated button" tabindex="0">
      <div class="visible content">Next</div>
      <div class="hidden content">
          <i class="right arrow icon"></i>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui vertical animated button" tabindex="0">
      <div class="hidden content">Shop</div>
      <div class="visible content">
          <i class="shop icon"></i>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui animated fade button" tabindex="0">
      <div class="visible content">Sign-up for a Pro account</div>
      <div class="hidden content">
          $12.99 a month
      </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `semantic-ui` WebJar version `2.0.7` is on the classpath?

Comment: I guess so, I get it through gradle - compile 'org.webjars:Semantic-UI:2.0.7', then I can access the semantic-ui files after deploy in tomcat through address : http://localhost:8080/projectname/webjars/Semantic-UI/2.0.7/semantic.min.js . I have no idea what is wrong...

Comment: Maybe you need to match the case in the URL you are using?

Answer (score 1):

**As expect you have to add contextpath in url to browser identify the resource**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.css">
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
<title>Index Page</title>
</head>
```

like this

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not using relative path to do this. Try injecting them in index file. I had the same issue.